# How to return a proper const_iterator to a collection of non-const pointers?

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a class encapsulating a vector of pointers to class `MyClass` (pointers instead of instances because `MyClass` is actually a base class for an extensive hierarchy of subclasses, instances of which are held in the collection). The vector can't hold const pointers, because the collection owns the objects and deletes them in its destructor.

Users of this collection are supposed to have read-only access to items in the collection. Regular `const_iterator` won't do the job here, because it would allow users of the class modify the items, so I made this typedef:

```
    class MyCollection
    {
    private:
        std::vector<MyClass*> backingCollection;
    public:
        typedef std::vector<MyClass const*>::const_iterator const_iterator;
```

`MyCollection` needs to have a begin and end methods to return these iterators. However, `backingCollection.begin()` returns regular `const_iterator`, so I had to hack together a horribly-looking cast:

```
    inline const_iterator begin() const 
    { 
          return *reinterpret_cast<const_iterator*>(&this->backingCollection.begin());           
    }
```

This worked fine while I was compiling the project only in Visual Studio, but GCC hates it:

```
error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]
```

I don't want to enable the permissive mode only because of this.

**What is the best solution here?** Is the whole idea with const iterators wrong? Is there a better way to convert the iterators?

Comment: What about creating a custom class derived from `std::iterator` using `MyClass const*` as its type, and have it encapsulate a regular `vector<MyClass*>::const_iterator` internally?  Then you have more control over what your custom iterator exposes to users.

Comment: _"The vector can't hold const pointers, because the collection owns the objects and deletes them in its destructor."_ You can delete a const pointer.

Answer (score 4):

use `.data()` instead of begin, which returns a pointer to const pointer, and implicitly cast to a pointer to `const` pointer to `const`.  For `end` return data plus size.

You lose debug instrumentation, and that is about it.

```
typedef MyClass const*const* const_iterator;

inline const_iterator begin() const { 
  return backingCollection.data();
}
inline const_iterator end() const { 
  return begin()+backingCollection.size();
}
```

Comment: Nice trick that works in this ad-hoc case. How to extend a solution that works for non-contiguous container ?

Comment: @sandwood write a transforming iterator.  Note that the only legacy iterator concept it can satisfy is input or output iterator I suspect; std ranges makes it more practical.

Answer (score 0):

As always, compiler is right :-)

You must use reinterpret_cast on the address of the backing_collection , then returning the const_iterator from the reinterpreted.

```
using ConstCollection = const std::vector<const MyClass*>;

inline auto begin() const { 
  return reinterpret_cast<ConstCollection*>&backingCollection)->cbegin();
}

inline auto end() const { 
  return reinterpret_cast<ConstCollection*>&backingCollection)->cend();
}
```